# How to Call Jquery from C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I've tried to call the [dialog-model jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message)

```
$(function () {
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
            modal: true
        });
    });
```

from C# using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "dialog();", true);
```

but the JQuery is executing after page load and not when I call the ScriptManager.

How can I do that the JQuery function  execute when the **ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript** it execute in C#?

Apparently I did not explain well: This jquery I call during postback when execute especific function, but is executting in the first postback. I want call the jquery during the code execution. Should be more specific?

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding of the difference between server-side code and client-side code.  The jQuery can't execute until the page is rendered to the browser *because it executes in the browser*.

Comment: I understand that. I know that I can execute javascript using ScriptManager and this function to normal javascript function but I've found How to do function this Jquery from C#.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking in that response.  But in general my advice to you is to move away from using the `ScriptManager` in general.  If you're going to be using jQuery and any other client-side code that's more complex than a single JavaScript statement then you're better off putting that in the client-side code and keeping it out of the server-side code.  In short, don't "call it from C#."  Just put the JavaScript code in the view/page/file/etc. where it belongs.

Comment: You need to make a named function that you can call via startup script.  Such as function DoTheDialog()

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I going to have present in the future but now I'll tried to execute this Jquery from C#. Because its should be launch afeter a specific occurrence during the server side execution...

Comment: Thanks @Brian but I tried that that already and the Jquery continues executing inmediatly when I charged the page without call to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
C#:
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "showMyDialog();", true);

Javascript:
<script>
function showMyDialog() {
  $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
    modal: true
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried to do that but the jquery its executed in every page postback inclusive when I not call the jquery function.... Any suggestion for correct that?

Comment: At what point in your code-behind are you calling RegisterStartupScript?  You'll want to call that at the point you want to open the dialog, like a button click event.

Comment: Well the first problem to solved is that the jquery only execute when I called it. The seconde is that I calling RegisterStartupScript when I an specific condition pass like a IF but I can't test it because the jquery execute every postback... I put it in the header ContendHolder.

Comment: I think for anyone to contribute more, you may need to post your entire updated page code, including the code-behind where you are calling RegisterStartupScript.  It is difficult to determine what you have at the moment.

Comment: Thnaks I post the code in the link below http://pastebin.ca/2408947. I hope that someone can check why the jquery is executting in every postback inclusive when the condition when the jquery is into is false...

Comment: Your function is likely running every time because it is the function defined for the jquery document load event.  Instead of "$(function showMyDialog() {", just define it as "function showMyDialog() {"

Comment: A lot of thanks [Michael](http://stackoverflow.com/users/511252/michael). That was finding, but nobody understand me. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, np.  Please mark this as answered, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is executed after the page is rendered. It cannot "call" or "run" c# code, unless you make a post/get to your webserver (which the server side handles).

c# is run on the server and javascript on the client.