# how to call jquery function call in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery

I want to show division for 5 seconds while i do every postback in c#.I am using below function to do that but it doesn't work.

I used this code on page load in c#.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "PostbackClick", "setTimeout(function() { $('#correct').fadeOut(1500); }, 5000)", true);
```

in aspx page

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/scripts/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#correct').hide();

    });
</script>

<img alt="" id="correct" src="Que-img/correct.png" />
```

Comment: are you already included the jquery script dependency?

Comment: works well and good for me.Can post what is "correct" and double check if u have jQuery included in page

Comment: Try to show division before postback on client using javascript.

Comment: post the html code too

Comment: @Frank59 not working....

Comment: @VivekParikh posted answer have  a look

Comment: @iJay i want to show image after postback button click not from start.so i have to hide it first of all.

Comment: @iJay it shows image first of all.

Comment: @VivekParikh updated code wid demo have a look

Comment: @iJay i have asp button so will it work?

Comment: @VivekParikh instead of image i used a paragraph with same id....change it as per your convenience ...it will works

Comment: offcourse it will work with asp too

Comment: @iJay not working... please help me can i do teamviewer?

Comment: post your aspx code dat is not working......full html code....including js

Answer (score 1):

use

```
    RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "PostbackClick", "$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function() { $('#correct').fadeIn(1500); }, 5000)});", true)
```

Because you have to wait for JQuery.ready before using jquery selectors. RegisterStartupScript actually happens before jquery ready. 
in my answer your setTimer  will executed on jquery ready

Answer (score 0):

You already **hiding the image** in `document.ready function`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$('#correct').hide(); // remove this line or comment 
        // because fadeOut will work on visible elements

       function hideImage() {
           setTimeout(function() { $('#correct').fadeOut(1500); }, 5000);
       };
    });
</script>
```

In **C#**

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(),"PostbackClick", "script",
                                        "hideImage();" true);
```

[How to Call Jquery from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280415/how-to-call-jquery-from-c-sharp) will help you

Comment: actually i want image to be disappear after 5 seconds.

Comment: not working..Btw i want to show image for 5 sec after postpack click.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i got your issue ...Modify your code as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#correct').hide();
    $('#btnId').click(function(){
          $('#correct').show();
          setTimeout(function() { $('#correct').fadeOut(1500); }, 5000);
    });
});
```

and remove

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "PostbackClick", "setTimeout(function() { $('#correct').fadeOut(1500); }, 5000)", true);
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TnvuR/)