# Call jquery click event from asp code behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

The front end of this code has already been developed, and uses jquery in multiple places to intercept the user's click.  Here I have a radio button that, when clicked, fires the event below. I need to make this even fire for the html input element from my code behind on the page load event to pre-fill the radio buttons.  How can I do this?

Jquery event to fire:

```
    //checkboxes
    $('.questions-form a.toggle').bind('click', function (event) {
           //jquery magic
     }
```

html elements that I need to select, or click:

```
                            <div id="form-error" style="display: none"></div>

                            <div class="questions-form" id="shipping-questions-form">

                                <div class="question question-textarea has-subquestions">
                                    <div class="question-intro clearfix">
                                        <h2>Did You Receive The Product As Ordered?</h2>

                                        <div class="no-yes answer-acceptable">
                                            <div class="no"><label class="label-1" for="shipping_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_not_acceptable">Not Acceptable</label></div>
                                            <a href="#" class="toggle"></a>
                                            <div class="yes"><label class="label-2" for="shipping_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_acceptable">Acceptable</label></div>
                                            <label class="universal-label"></label>

                                            <input type="radio" id="shipping_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_not_acceptable" name="shipping-question-ID-product-received-as-ordered" value="Not Acceptable" runat="server">
                                            <input type="radio" id="shipping_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_acceptable" name="shipping-question-ID-product-received-as-ordered" value="Acceptable" checked="true" runat="server">

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: While it's totally possible, it's likely a poor design if you need to do this. Perhaps you should separate out what needs server side interaction from what doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method (Page, Type, String, String, Boolean);
```

where the parameters are

```
**page**
Type: System.Web.UI.Page
The page object that is registering the client script block.
**type**
Type: System.Type
The type of the client script block. This parameter is usually specified by using the typeof operator (C#) or the GetType operator (Visual Basic) to retrieve the type of the control that is registering the script.
**key**
Type: System.String
A unique identifier for the script block.
**script**
Type: System.String
The script to register.
**addScriptTags**
Type: System.Boolean
true to enclose the script block with <script> and </script> tags; otherwise, false.
```

Example to use see :[how to call jquery function call in asp.net c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442702/how-to-call-jquery-function-call-in-asp-net-c)

Comment: In the code above, I have multiple inputs that have the same click event.  How can I call this function for a specific radio input, say "shipping-question-ID-product-received-as-ordered"?

Comment: place it inside protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

Comment: I am a bit confused...I need to send the click event "shipping-question-ID-product-received-as-ordered", can I still do this using the method described in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The following code performed the needed functionality. I invoked this function by "clicking" the anchor attached to the object.

```
<div class="no"><label class="label-1" for="shipping_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_not_acceptable">Not Acceptable</label></div>
<a href="#" class="toggle" runat="server" id="shipping_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_link"></a>
```

Then in the code behind:

```
var autoRunScript = string.Format("<script>$(function() {{ $('#{0}').click(); }} );</script>", shipping_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_link.ClientID);
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("keyClientBlock", autoRunScript);
```